# How do I reinforce a drawer bottom?

Tags: furniture, drawers, self-assembly-furniture

I recently bought a self-assembly wardrobe.  After assembling it, the drawer bottoms were not held in place by enough wood (I think the groove for the drawer base was too close to the bottom of the drawer).

I have two questions:

1. Does anyone have any tips for reinforcing these? They have already broken three times, and I've tried additional screws, wood glue and even new pieces of wood to fix them.
2. Is there any way of simply buying the instructions separately so that I can build it with higher quality wood?

Comment: Can you please post pictures of your drawer bottoms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One website for furniture plans that my wife recently found is [ana-white.com](http://ana-white.com/). Best thing is, they're free! Each article/blog post has a materials list and instructions.

There are quite a few plans for near-duplicates of brand-name furniture makers' products.

Here's [instructions for a dresser](http://ana-white.com/2010/02/plans-finally-dresser-maybe-not.html) from the website. (I'm not sure exactly what you mean by a wardrobe, since you mentioned it had drawers. When I hear wardrobe I normally think Chronicles of Narnia style.)

Comment: No - our wardrobe has doors and no witches!  :-)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - thanks.